# How to configure Spring Cloud AWS messaging with annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-aws

How would I configure Spring Cloud AWS  XML config with annotations?

I am especially interested in changing default taskExecutor.

Answer (score 3):

I found that there is `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory`  used to configure for AWS messaging via Java  .
So changing default `taskExecutor` is just matter for overriding this default container factory bean. Something like this:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    ConcurrentTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(executor);
    factory.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    return factory;
}
```